# Nagios/SNMP - devices alerting when ppp/tun connections cycle

Tags: linux, monitoring, ppp, nagios, snmp

Sorry if this is a repeat. I searched, but with no luck.

I'm using SNMPd on an openwrt/wr host with some ppp and tun connections.  These connections get IDs in the if table, and will actually get a new ID whenever the tunnels reconnect.

Nagios (check_mk), when that happens, complains that an interface went down; oh, and a different one with the same name came up right afterward.  In the meantime, it's iterating over so many interfaces that the reports are of 'interface 4933 down'; and an snmpwalk shows close to 4932 datapoints before it.

How are the helpful folks here handling a monitoring situation like that?

Comment: I suspect that when Docker containers cycle up and down, that the march of interface numbers is the same mechanism or issue.  The solution for one could be the same as for the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, so here's an answer so I'm not [denvercoder9](https://xkcd.com/979/).

Adding a new config to the snmpd.conf seems to have both trimmed the interface march as well as prevented complaints.

```
interface_replace_old yes
```

I think that's the one.  It could be that simple.

Try it yourself if you run into the same problem, and let me know if I've got it wrong.